# If I delete a child branch and check the changes in, will my parent branch be affected?

Tags: branching-and-merging, tfvc

I have a need to delete a branch. I realized that I created it from the wrong parent (and really the code in it now is wrong).

I'd like to just delete it and create a new branch off the correct parent.

If I delete the child branch and check in the change, will any of the items in my parent branch be impacted? In other words, will all of those items in the parent branch be deleted as well?

I don't need the branch hanging around for any reason, so tf destroy is on the table, I just don't want to impact my parent branch in any way.

Answer (score 0):

No your parent branch will be unaffected, except for one thing, it will retain the historical relationship to the incorrectly created child branch. So in the Merge window, it may show up as a potential target branch.

If you want to prevent that from happening, you should destroy (instead of delete) the incorrectly created branch.